# changing the src of an image using select box options and via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Its been a while that I'm trying to change the src of my image using JavaScript `addEventListener`. But it isn't changing the src. The following example to explain my situation:

```
let bulbImage = $.querySelector(".bulb-image");

let turnOnOption = $.querySelector(".bulb-on");
let trunOffOption = $.querySelector(".bulb-off");

turnOnOption.addEventListener("click" , turnOnFunction);

function turnOnFunction () {
    bulbImage.setAttribute("src" , "./images/bulbon.gif");
}

trunOffOption.addEventListener("click" , turnOffFunction);

function turnOffFunction () {
    bulbImage.setAttribute("src" , "./images/bulboff.gif");
}
```

For the record in my mini project, I'm not using any framework and this is very simple and easy code so there is no bug.

the html code is :

```html
<img src="./images/bulboff.gif" class="bulb-image" alt="bulboff">
<select class="selectbox">
  <option value="Turn ON" class="bulb-on">Turn ON</option>
  <option value="Turn OFF" class="bulb-off">Turn OFF</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is `$` a reference to? The `document`?

Comment: let $ = document;

Comment: Then your code is already working: https://jsfiddle.net/j4fukaeL/. If it's not working for you then most likely you've just got the image paths wrong.

Comment: Also, **do not use `$` as an alias for the** `document`. That's a really bad convention to use as `$` already has several other widely used meaning (eg. jQuery, and Chrome uses it as syntactic sugar for `document.querySelector`). Overriding that is confusing and may break functionality.

Comment: yeah , just check that out ... it seems its not very good idea to use $ as document

Comment: where is your `<select>` box element ? please add HTML part of this.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function changeImg() {
  if (document.getElementById("select_id").value === 'Turn ON') {
    document.getElementsByClassName("bulb-image")[0].src = "https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("bulb-image")[0].src = "https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/300";
  }
}
```

```css
select {
  border: none;
  margin: 20px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<select class="selectbox" onchange="changeImg()" id="select_id">
  <option value="Turn ON" class="bulb-on">Turn ON</option>
  <option value="Turn OFF" class="bulb-off">Turn OFF</option>
</select>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" class="bulb-image" alt="bulboff">
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use  change event  and the select elements values

```html
<img src="./images/bulboff.gif" class="bulb-image" alt="bulboff">
<select class="selectbox">
  <option value="Turn ON" >Turn ON</option>
  <option value="Turn OFF">Turn OFF</option>
</select>
```

```
const
  bulbImage  = document.querySelector('.bulb-image')
, turnOption =  document.querySelector('.selectbox')
  ;
turnOption.addEventListener( 'change', function()
  {
  if ( turnOption.value === 'Turn ON' ) bulbImage.src = './images/bulbon.gif';
  if ( turnOption.value === 'Turn OFF' ) bulbImage.src = './images/bulboff.gif';
  })
```

You can also use a JS object:

```js
const
  bulbImage  = document.querySelector('#bulb-image')
, turnOption = document.querySelector('#select_id')
, imgSrc =
  { 'Turn ON'  : 'https://picsum.photos/id/1/200'
  , 'Turn OFF' : 'https://picsum.photos/id/2/200'
  }
  ;
turnOption.onchange = e =>
  {
  bulbImage.src = imgSrc[ turnOption.value ];
  }
```

```css
select {
  border  : none;
  margin  : 1em 0;
  padding : .4em;
  cursor  : pointer;
  }
img {
  display : block;
  }
```

```html
<select class="selectbox" id="select_id">
  <option value="Turn ON"  selected > Turn ON  </option>
  <option value="Turn OFF"          > Turn OFF </option>
</select>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200" id="bulb-image" alt="bulbOnOff">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>

<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>
```

Comment: unsure how this answers the question, why would they change it to be buttons instead of a select element?